# Not seeing alt tag content for images

Tags: image

Is there accessibility improvements with the latest version of EE?

Currently our site doesn't have alt content for images. Wouldn't this be covered in the file upload process or shouldn't this be a field on the admin page when adding an image to a page.

Answer (score 1):

You could  create in the Field Manager of the Control Panel  an 'alt' channel  Field, and place it inside your template.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="test" limit="10"}
    <img src='image.png' alt='{my_alt_field}' >
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0):

as Stephane said. This gives you the added SEO benefit that you can change the alt text for each page where you use the image. Same goes for links, i normally create a link title field whenever there's a link field.